# Selecting values that are not null or empty does not work

Tags: sql

I am running a query and trying to select a value only when it is not null or empty. I am using `value IS NOT NULL and value <> ' '`. However I am still getting some blank values. Any thoughts?

Full query:

```
SELECT T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] FROM ORDR T0
WHERE T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] = '02' OR T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] IS NULL AND
 (T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL AND T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] <>' ')
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to wrap those first 2 conditions in brackets, otherwise, you will get all records where `T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] = '02'` regardless of the contents of `T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER]`.

```
SELECT T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] FROM ORDR T0
WHERE (T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] = '02' OR T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] IS NULL) AND
 (T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL AND T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] <>' ')
```

The way you have it now, the query executes this way, probably not what you want:

```
SELECT T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] FROM ORDR T0
WHERE T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] = '02' OR 
      (T0.[U_FORECAST_ORDER] IS NULL AND T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL AND T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] <>' ')
```

Remember that `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`.

Comment: I'll have to make sure and never leave out the parentheses

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
(T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL AND T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] <>' ')
```

To:

```
t0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] IS NOT NULL **OR** T0.[U_QUOTE_NUMBER] <> '')
```

Comment: I tried that just now, still getting the same results.

Comment: Can you please post sample data from the tables then? Also, inclose the first two parameters in () as well. SQL logic requires them.

Comment: No. Sample output is at <a href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/cl581e2oimgjiru/Query%20Preview.txt?dl=0">file</a>